# DOS Batch command to process 1 file at a time

Tags: dos

I am trying to execute a certain task where i am required to read files (one at a time) from a folder which can have undefined number of files. I need to be able to MOVE the first file in the folder to a new location and then execute another task with another batch file.The main aim is to read one files at a time instead of doing a *.* which will read all files at once.
Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: To put the question in a different way : Is there a way to copy  the first file (only) in a folder instead of copying all files?

Comment: is there a pattern to the name of the first file in a folder?

Comment: No - these are dynamically named files, and also the order of dates and name do not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a for command something like this:

```
for /R c:\test\src %i IN (*.*) DO (
MOVE %i C:\test\dest
YourBatch.bat C:\test\dest\%~nxi
)
```

If you are putting this command in a batch file you will need to double up the % symbols like this:

```
for /R c:\test\src %%i IN (*.*) DO (
MOVE %%i C:\test\dest
YourBatch.bat C:\test\dest\%%~nxi
)
```

In the YourBatch.bat file access the file name using %1% something like this:

```
@echo off
type %1%
```

### EDIT:

To only process one file simply exit at the end of the first loop:

```
for /R c:\test\src %%i IN (*.*) DO (
MOVE %%i C:\test\dest
YourBatch.bat C:\test\dest\%%~nxi
exit
)
```

Comment: can you explain the purpose of %%~nxi ?
Thanks !

Comment: It seems the code you have provided runs continuously in a loop for (*.*) I would like it to stop after reading the first file.

Comment: The ~nx in the middle of %i means that you only get the file name and extention. n = file name, x = extention.

Comment: I've added a version that exits after the first itteration. I tried using goto :EOF but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to take a look at [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(WS.10).aspx):

> Selects and executes a command on a file or set of files. This command is useful for batch processing.

Comment: But I would like to have a single batch file for copying 1 files at a time, lets say I have 5 batch files as 5 Steps (each independent of other step) and the first step needs to read the first file in the folder instead of reading all files in a loop since this step will have no connection with Step2.

Comment: In short is there a way to copy the first file in the folder instead of copying all files?

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to do it.  it uses some extensions to the SET command:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b') DO (
   CALL SET /a x = !x! +1
   if !x! == 1 (
      REM do your work here. the call to move is an example
      CALL ECHO moving %%a
      CALL MOVE %%a .. 
   )
)
```

[here](http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm) are some details

Comment: I find it interesting that you use "CALL" the way that you are here... does that work?  What is the reason for it?