# Move files with .bat ONE AT A TIME

Tags: file, batch-file, console

I have a .bat file that moves everything that starts with TEST_ and ends in .prn. The problem is, if more than one file is moved, something will break. Is there a way to add in a parameter to just move ONE FILE per run?

Original Code:

```
move s:\FILES\TEST_*.prn s:\ANOTHER_PLACE\Processed
```

This code works, but if two people uploaded a file at the same time, it would move both files, causing the server on the other end to have issues.

Comment: Check this: it has the perfect code that I implemented and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094800/dos-batch-command-to-process-1-file-at-a-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to execute `move` once per file, not all files at once. You can do this:

```
FOR %%f IN (s:\FILES\TEST_*.prn) DO (
    move %%f s:\ANOTHER_PLACE\Processed\
)
```

So, for each file `%%f` matching `s:\FILES\TEST_*.prn`, you execute `move`.

Comment: Ok, so i ran that and every file that started with TEST_ was moved to processed. What i want is it to exit right after it moves that first time, right? To move one file, then STOP and not move another one until i run the .bat file again.

Comment: Right, so i put in exit right at the end of the do loop and it does exactly what i needed. It moves one file, then stops. One file per run.

Comment: I don't understand..so is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If I understanded good this is what you want:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "InputDir=s:\FILES"
Set "OutputDir=s:\ANOTHER_PLACE\Processed"
Set "Pattern=TEST_*.prn"

FOR %%# IN ("%InputDir%\%Pattern%") DO ((Move "%%f" "%OutputDir%\" && Exit /B 0) || (Exit /B 1))
```

It moves the first file found alphabetically and then exits.

Also it returns 0 if file moved right, returns 1 if file can't be moved for any reason.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR %%f IN ("s:\FILES\TEST_*.prn") DO set "file=%%~ff"
if defined file move "%file%" "s:\ANOTHER_PLACE\Processed"
```